How to filter a list within a list in Angular?
I have a List of Staff Members. Inside the list of staff members are a list of clients each with their own ID.
I want to filter down into another array only the list of staff that have clients that match a certain client id. How do I do that?
So for example

I have 20 Staff Members
Each Staff member can have hundreds of clients or can have ZERO clients
Each staff member can have the same client (hence the reason for this question)
Each Client has their own ID
I need to get only the list of staff that has a client with a certain ID

This is what I have tried so far but this is incorrect. It gives me the error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')


 let newStaffList = this.staffModelList?.clientList?.filter(
                        (c) => c.ClientId == ClientId
                    );


you are trying to filter the clients, but you want to filter the staff by the clients. That's the confusion. Try this:
// you filter the staff that has the client
this.staffModelList.filter(staff => {
  // by checking which staff has said client in it's list
  return staff.clientList.some(c => c.ClientId == ClientId);
});

